# Angular 4 - Reading metadata about Services (@Injectable)

Tags: angular, service, metadata

I want to know, if it is possible to read meta information about an injected service class?

For example:
Which component injected my service? Somthing like injector API

> ...   constructor(private _viewContainer: ViewContainerRef){
>         console.log(_viewContainer.injector)   } ...

## Service...

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  constructor() { ... }

}
```

## Component...

```
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
        //here I want to read the meta information about the service
  }

}
```

Comment: Help me understand: What problem are you actually trying to solve (meaning what will you do with the info?  Do you want a reference to the component `type` or the actual instance? Within the constructor, you are already running code in the context of the component that injected the service, so you could just use `this` to get a reference to it.

Comment: Your question about my actual problem has brought me to rethink my approach!... What i have tried to solve is a mapping from multiple components that share a service... so that one component can read which other componentent used the same service...Its akward to explain and finally made no sence at all... I now use directives ... i guess the problem is solved... thanx anyway for your feedback...